# 'UnexpectedTagNameException' and Element should have been "select" but was "div" error using 'Select' function through Selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

In this form selection of drop down is not working.

[image: This is image]

In above image I want to select 'Borrowing Capacity'

and I write code for it

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
    WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver();
    //driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.ia.ca/");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"nav-secondaire\"]/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"nav-secondaire\"]/div[1]/ul/li[4]/ul/li[1]/section/ul/li[1]/a")).click();

   //DropDown code
    WebElement selectMyElement =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"grille-zone-cta\"]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]"));
    Select cal = new Select(selectMyElement);
    cal.selectByIndex(1);
```

It gives me exception

> 'UnexpectedTagNameException'

and error message is

> Element should have been "select" but was "div"

[image: HTML tags]

Comment: Why use the long xpath when the element has a defined id?

Comment: `Select cal = new Select(selectMyElement);`, but before that, `selectMyElement` is an `div` -> `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".../div[2]/div[1]"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
'UnexpectedTagNameException' : Element should have been "select" but was "div"
```

...implies that you have used `Select` class to interact with the element where as the element was a `<div>`.

To `click()` on the element with text as **Borrowing Capacity** you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//h4[@class='bta-description' and text()='Our calculators']//following::div[@class='bta-select-table row']//b[@class='button']"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='selectric-items']//li[contains(., 'Borrowing Capacity')]"))).click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: BorrowingCapacity]